# Convert a timestamp string to timestamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I have a string "1597363200000" that is already a timestamp. I just need the raw timestamp value. How do I get the timestamp value in javascript? So what I want is just 1597363200000.

I already tried Date.parse

Comment: Before you post, search the site to make sure your question hasn’t been answered
1.Summarize the problem
2.Provide details and any research
3.When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to convert this string into a number right?

```
const timestamp = parseInt("1597363200000")
```